# simple function error "Variable not in scope" haskell

Tags: haskell

I have just started to code Haskell today, stuck on building function that takes an integer from user, multiply it by 3, adds one and checks if it is Even. returns the output as Boolean, true if even.
Sorry if the code is too faulty, I'm a Haskell newbie.

```
checkIfEven :: Int -> Bool
x <- readLn
let checkIfEven x = (even ((x*3)+1))
print checkIfEven   

 error:
    Variable not in scope: checkIfEven :: Int -> Bool
```

Answer (score 5):

I/O has to be handled explicitly in Haskell, as `readLn` is not a function; it's an IO action. It is simpler to start with a true function that takes the value to check as an argument:

```
checkIfEven :: Int -> Bool
checkIfEven x = even (x*3 + 1)
```

Note that the parentheses are not part of the call to `even`, but rather "grouping" the expression `x * 3 + 1`, as `even x*3 + 1` is parsed as `(even x) * 3 + 1`.

Now that we have a pure function, we can apply it to a value input by the user.

```
program :: IO Bool
program = do
    x <- readLn
    return (checkIfEven (read x))
```

A few things to note:

1. `<-` is not an assignment operator; it's special syntax inside a `do` construct with "extracts" a value from (in this context) an IO action.
2. `x` will be a string, so you need to parse it to get an `Int` value for `checkIfEven`. `read` is a simple way to do that; we're ignoring the possibility that the user may enter a string that can *not* be parsed as an `Int`.
3. `return` doesn't return a value from a function (note we did not use it in the definition of `checkIfEven`. Rather, it "lifts" a value into a new IO action, has `program` has to be value of type `IO Bool`, not `Bool`.

Note that a `do` construct provides an imperative-looking way to work with IO actions. You can work directly with the underlying functions and values; in this case, we could have simply written

```
program = fmap (checkIfEven . read) readLn
```

The full explanation of how IO (and monads in general) work is beyond the scope of this question; hopefully, this will give you an idea of what to focus on as you study the topic further.

Comment: It is very honorable from you to provide such a good answer from a not perfect formed question, and to a new user... I admire that.